# Printing keys of the HTTPClient JSON

Tags: java, json

I started practicing Java while being an intern so I wanted to ask regarding the following

***1. This is how a print the entire JSON:***

[image]

This is how it's printed (sorry, I had to hide some data)
[image]

**Question**: ***How can I print a particular key of this JSON (e.g. conceptClass)?***

Comment: You would need to use some JSON manipulation library for processing json. Maybe you should use jackson or `org.json:json:*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use JSON manipulation libraries like Jackson. Please refer below for examples,
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-collection-array

Answer (score 0):

Using org.json, here in this solution.

(optional)In the first part, generate a json using JSONObject

```
org.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("name", "max");
jsonObject.put("age", "10");
        
String payload = jsonObject.toString();
        
System.out.println(payload);
```

Then using convert string to JSON again:

```
org.json.JSONObject newJsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject(payload);
```

Then using key get its associate value:

```
System.out.println(newJsonObject.get("age"));
```

output:
`10`